# hbase-default.xml file seems to be for and old version of HBase (null), this version is 0.94.6-cdh4.3.0

Tags: osgi, hbase

I am creating an OSGi bundle in which a Sling servlet need to use HBase.  I am getting the following error.  I've googled this and the answers I find are pretty vague, and some of them contradictory.  I have HBase 0.94.6 running on my localhost, and the necessary jars are Maven dependencies in the project.  They are also included in the EmbedDependency tag.  I have tried including hbase-default.xml in the bundle's root (i.e., in src/main/resources), and I have the following in maven-bundle-plugin's configuration/exception tag:

```
<Include-Resource>{maven-resources}</Include-Resource>
```

If I understand correctly, this should result in the file being built with the bundle, and I can see it in the resulting jar file.  But I still get the following error from Felix when the bundle is deployed.  Does anyone know how to make this message go away?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: hbase-default.xml file seems to be for and old version of HBase (null), this version is 0.94.6-cdh4.3.0 
  at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration.checkDefaultsVersion(HBaseConfiguration.java:68)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration.addHbaseResources(HBaseConfiguration.java:100)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration.create(HBaseConfiguration.java:111)
  at com.adobe.corona.repo.acquisition.TestServlet.activate(TestServlet.java:46)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was that I had to add this:

```
   Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(HBaseConfiguration.class.getClassLoader());
```

This was mentioned in another thread, but there were several proposed solutions there.  I tried this one early on, but it didn't work at the time.  I probably needed to restart Felix or delete the bundle or something.  Anyway, this finally resolved it.

Comment: this helped me fix the same problem in jruby, using hbase 0.98.6.1. My code worked when run directly during tests/etc locally, but got this error when deployed as a gem. For jruby I used this line: `java.lang.Thread.currentThread.setContextClassLoader(HBaseConfiguration.to_java.get_class.getClassLoader)`